# Python 3: Searching A Large Text File With REGEX

Tags: python, regex, text, python-3.x

I wish to search a large text file with regex and have set-up the following code:

```
import re

regex = input("REGEX: ")

SearchFunction = re.compile(regex)

f = open('data','r', encoding='utf-8')

result = re.search(SearchFunction, f)

print(result.groups())

f.close()
```

Of course, this doesn't work because the second argument for `re.search` should be a string or buffer. However, I cannot insert all of my text file into a string as it is too long (meaning that it would take forever). What is the alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regex parse stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634376/python-regex-parse-stream)

Comment: Assuming your file is on your local drive and it's not bigger than your available memory, loading the file will take substantially less time than running the regex. Have you actually tried to read the whole thing first?

Comment: @beerbajay, CPUs can process strings faster than HDDs can read them. Simple expressions will run faster than reading them from disk. (Unless you are on a pretty fast SSD/RAID).

Comment: You're correct of course; I was reacting to "it would take forever".

Answer (score 7):

You check if the pattern matches for each line. This won't load the entire file to the memory:

```
for line in f:
    result = re.search(SearchFunction, line)
```

Comment: [This then becomes my new code?](http://pastie.org/3511298) The problem is: my printed result is just a `()`. Changing the 11th line to `print(result)` just returns something like `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002A73648>`. What should the 11th line actually be to give correct results?

Comment: Or if the file is a large binary file (not text based lines) you could load and regex portions of it at a time.

Comment: @Secator: There is a problem with this method of matching regex line by line. What if a regex is such that it matches across 2 or more lines? Something like this one - http://pastie.org/3511422 (That regex was made by me sometime back, and your code surely won't work in that case)

Comment: @PushpakDagade Steven's answer can be used in such cases.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a memory-mapped file with the [mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) module. Think of it as a file pretending to be a string (or the opposite of a StringIO). You can find an example in this [Python Module of the Week article about mmap](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/mmap/#regular-expressions) by Doug Hellman.