# Python re for custom sequence type

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a custom sequence-like object, `s`, that inherits `collections.Sequence` and implements custom `__len__` and `__getitem__`. It represents a big blob of strings (>4GB) and is lazily loaded (I can't afford loading all into memory).

I'd like to do RE match on it, `re.compile('some-pattern').match(s)`, but it fails with `TypeError: expected string or buffer`.

In practice, pattern is not something like `'.*'` that requires the entire `s` to be loaded; it usually takes the first few tens of bytes to match; however, I can't tell beforehand the exact number of bytes and I want keep it general, therefore I don't want to do something like `re.compile('some-pattern').match(s[:1000])`.

Any suggestions on how to create a `str`-like object that is accepted by `re`?

The following code illustrates my unsuccessful attempts. Inheriting from `str` is not working either.

```
In [1]: import re, collections

In [2]: class MyStr(collections.Sequence):
    def __len__(self): return len('hello')
    def __getitem__(self, item): return 'hello'[item]
   ...:

In [3]: print(re.compile('h.*o').match(MyStr()))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-df08913b19d7> in <module>()
----> 1 print(re.compile('h.*o').match(MyStr()))

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

If the big blob of string comes from a single big file then I can use `mmap` and it should work. However, my case is more complicated. I have multiple big files, I `mmap`ed each of them and have a custom class that is a concatenated view of them. I actually want to perform the RE match starting from any given position in the view. I omit such details in the original question, but I think it might be helpful to someone who wants to understand why I have such weird requirement.

Comment: Do you have disk restrictions as well? You can temporarily concatenate all of your files into a single file then `mmap` it for searching, if disk size is not an issue.

Comment: Inheriting from `str` works for me: `class Class(str): pass \n c = Class('hello') \n re.compile('h.*o').match(c)` Can you please show why it is not working for you?

Comment: @zwer, concatenating all files is not an option. It's way too slow.

Comment: @Sanyash, in your code it essentially loads the entire string into memory before constructing it. It is not an option for me.

Comment: it sounds like you need to implement a custom `re_match` method that will do regex's on chunks of the string, so if you want to make it general and not loaded into memory, you will have to do something like `re.compile('some-pattern').match(s[:1000])`, but buried in an object method so then you don't have to see it in your calling code

Comment: @VinceW. the problem here is I don't know when `s[:1000]` fails to match, whether it fails because `1000` is not big enough, and will match if it is `2000`; or it won't match whatever follows `s[:1000]`. Not to hard code a 1000 is what I meant by "general". Of course, my goal here is vulnerable to patterns like `.*non_existent_string`, but I'm fine with this corner case.

Comment: Are you able to know in advance a maximum length that would be required to match? For example if you know you would never be interested in matches that were longer than 500 then 1000 length chunks that are advanced by 500 would work. If you could conceivably have a match that is as long as the string... well... that would be harder

Comment: How strict is your need to be able to run the regex across the concatenation of the files? This https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546759/529630 stats`re` will accept mmapped files as well as strings. It links to this example https://pymotw.com/3/mmap/#regular-expressions

Comment: @Dunes, in fact, my last paragraph of my original question mentioned mmap. The ability to run on concatenation of multiple files is required.

Comment: In that case the only real way to this and still capture matches that cross the file boundary is to not use python, but rather command line tools like `cat` and `grep`. That, or find someway or guarantee there will never be a matches that straddle a file boundary (maybe a regex that does not have include new line characters and all files must be newline terminated).

Comment: the `jsre` package has some examples that seem relevant, e.g. https://jsre.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#large-file-processing .  that said, I'd still go with an external process like `grep` (as suggested by @Dunes, but maybe doing its `stdin` handling in python)

Answer (score 12):

There is **no** special method you can implement that'll let `re.match()` accept your custom class and not require that you read all data into memory.

That's because there currently is no special method that'll let your custom class act as a [buffer-protocol object](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects). `re` methods only accept `str` strings (which do implement the buffer protocol), and `unicode` strings (and subclasses, data accessed directly, not via `__unicode__`). The `re` methods do not accept arbitrary sequences, and only the buffer protocol would let you avoid reading the whole thing into memory in one go.

Rather than try to implement a custom object, however, if your data is stored entirely in a single on-disk file (but is too large to read into memory), you want to use [*memory mapping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). Memory mapping uses the virtual memory facilities of your OS to access portions of a file as sections of memory.

The virtual memory subsystem lets your OS manage more memory than your computer has physically available in the form of RAM, by putting chunks of memory ('pages') on to your harddisk instead. As memory is accessed, the OS keeps swapping out pages from disk to physical memory and back again. Memory mapping simply expands this functionality to existing files, making it possible to treat a very large file as a single, large string where the OS will ensure that parts that you try to access are available in memory when needed.

In Python, this functionality is available via the [`mmap` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html), and a memory mapped file is **implements the buffer protocol**. You can pass such objects directly to `re.match()`, and Python and your OS will work together to search the data in the file for a match.

So, given a large file `filename = '/path/to/largefile'` and regular expression `pattern`, this would search the file for a match at the start for your pattern:

```
import re
import mmap
import os

fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY)
mapped = mmap.mmap(fd, 0)
matched = re.match(pattern, mapped)
```

If you have *multiple files*, you need to find a way to concatenate them. Virtually, or physically. If you are using Linux, you can concatenate files virtually by using a network block device, or you can use a FUSE virtual file system. See [*A virtual file containing the concatenation of other files*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94041/a-virtual-file-containing-the-concatenation-of-other-files).

Comment: thanks for the information. I actually mentioned mmap in the last paragraph of my original question and I do need to be able to run on concatenation of multiple files. I'd like to confirm, there is no way to implement buffer-protocol object in pure python, right?

Comment: @KanLi The problem with the buffer protocol is that it is not iteration based - it assumes some contiguous block of memory inside which your data is scattered in fixed strides. If the buffer allowed multiple blocks of memory, then you could `mmap` multiple files and wrap their memory regions inside such a super-buffer structure.

Comment: @KanLi: the buffer protocol specifically deals with contiguous memory; the protocol defines a start address and length (the data itself is an array that can be multidimensional, of structured data of fixed size). If you are on Linux, you could try to treat multiple files as a single file with a [network block device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94041/a-virtual-file-containing-the-concatenation-of-other-files).

Comment: @KanLi: if all results are fully contained in single files, I'd just mmap them all and iterate the re.match over all.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel: `re.match()` anchors from the start of a string, you can’t just start with a ‘partial string’ (e.g. a later file) and even without the anchor the match might bridge across a file join.

Comment: @KanLi: I think you have to implement not a custom str, but a custom (C ext) Py_buffer linking several mmaps together using this: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#c.Py_buffer.suboffsets. How is above me.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel: no, you can’t because strings are single-dimensional arrays (`ndim` set to 0), what you found only applies to multidimensional arrays (PIL array style). The `re` module uses the [`PyBUF_SIMPLE` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#shape-strides-suboffsets) when requesting access to the buffer, requiring `ndim` to be set to 0. See the [`_sre.c` module source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6fec905de5c139017f36b212e54cac46959808fe/Modules/_sre.c#L374-L378).

Comment: @Martijn upon inspection of _sre.c you are right. You also can't easily mmap files to consecutive memory, unless they are exactly sized to multiples of page size. (Are they?)

Comment: @JürgenStrobel: the kernel takes care of mmaped files occupying consecutive memory addresses. Those addresses are virtual, as all memory access is from the perspective of processes. You can't force the kernel to place multiple mmapped files back to back in that memory space, nor would the kernel allow apps to treat the memory space as one.

Comment: @Martijn I meant back-to-back mmaps, using the fixed or whatever flag instead of relying on the kernel choosing the address.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel: there is no way to use `MAP_FIXED` from the Python `mmap()` module, which calls the `mmap()` system call with `NULL` as the address argument.