# regular expression on stream instead of string?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose you want to do regular expression search and extract over a pipe, but the pattern may cross multiple lines, How to do it? Maybe a regular expression library work for a stream?

I hope do this job using Python library? But any solution will be OK, a library not a cmd line tool of course.

BTW, I know how to solve my current problem, just seeking a general solution.

If no such libray exists, why regular library can not work with stream given the regular mathing algorithm never need backward scaning.

Comment: Can you post some sample input and your expected output?

Comment: You can make the regex match across line, but usually, you will need everything to be there for matching to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are after a general solution, your algorithm would need to look something like:

1. Read a chunk of the stream into a buffer.
2. Search for the regexp in the buffer
3. If the pattern matches, do whatever you want with the match, discard the start of the buffer up to `match.end()` and go to step 2.
4. If the pattern does not match, extend the buffer with more data from the stream

This could end up using a lot of memory if no matches are found, but it is difficult to do better in the general case (consider trying to match `.*x` as a multi-line regexp in a large file where the only `x` is the last character).

If you know more about the regexp, you might have other cases where you can discard part of the buffer.

Comment: Looking at @ITNinja's answer, the algorithm I gave isn't perfect either.  For example, if you had an expression `x*` and the buffer ends in an `x`, the algorithm may give you the wrong match if the stream contains more `x` characters.  Hopefully it is enough to give you some idea of how you might handle such situations with the `re` library though.

Comment: Now I got @ITNinja's point. Indeed, once '.*' presents,   all stream need be buffered very likely. But libraries work on a stream still have an advantage if designed properlly, they pipeline data generating and matching. But the proper implementation need rewriting RE library in lower level which is beyond my patinet and ability.

Comment: I just found another solution: pexpect http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal I don't see how your `pexpect` link is related to the OP's problem

Comment: `pexpect` is a python library. You can pass it a file descriptor for the pipe that OP has, and then you can use `.expect()` with a regex to parse. The value that pexpect adds is handling buffering and blocking of the pipe for you.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem for searching a stream using classic pattern matching. You may want to subclass the Matcher class of my solution [streamsearch-py](https://github.com/gitagon/streamsearch-py) and perform regex matching in the buffer. Check out the included kmp_example.py below for a template. If it turns out classic Knuth-Morris-Pratt matching is all you need, then your problem would be solved right now with this little open source library :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright 2014-2015 @gitagon. For alternative licenses contact the author.
# 
# This file is part of streamsearch-py.
# streamsearch-py is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
# 
# streamsearch-py is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
# along with streamsearch-py.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


from streamsearch.matcher_kmp import MatcherKMP
from streamsearch.buffer_reader import BufferReader

class StringReader():
    """for providing an example read() from string required by BufferReader"""
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.s = string
        self.i = 0

    def read(self, buf, cnt):
        if self.i >= len(self.s): return -1
        r = self.s[self.i]
        buf[0] = r
        result = 1
        print "read @%s" % self.i, chr(r), "->", result
        self.i+=1
        return result

def main():

    w = bytearray("abbab")
    print "pattern of length %i:" % len(w), w
    s = bytearray("aabbaabbabababbbc")
    print "text:", s
    m = MatcherKMP(w)
    r = StringReader(s)
    b = BufferReader(r.read, 200)
    m.find(b)
    print "found:%s, pos=%s " % (m.found(), m.get_index())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output is

```
pattern of length 5: abbab
text: aabbaabbabababbbc
read @0 a -> 1
read @1 a -> 1
read @2 b -> 1
read @3 b -> 1
read @4 a -> 1
read @5 a -> 1
read @6 b -> 1
read @7 b -> 1
read @8 a -> 1
read @9 b -> 1
found:True, pos=5
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: true. pasted  `kmp_example.py`

Answer (score -2):

I do not believe that it is possible to use a regular expression on a stream, because without an entire piece of data, you cant make a positive match. This means that you would only have a probable match.

However, as @James Henstridge stated, you could use buffers to overcome this.

Comment: This doesn't sound correct. A simple regex is a DFA. Each input character is a state transition in that DFA. A particular transition(s) signifies a match. Barring advanced features or implementation performance constraints, full string is not needed to evaluate a DFA on a string.