# How to read a file and extract data between multiline patterns?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I have a file from which I need to extract one piece of data, delimited by (possibly) multiline fixed patterns

```
some data ... [my opening pattern
is here
and can be multiline] the data 
I want to extract [my ending
pattern which can be
multiline as well] ... more data
```

These patterns are fixed in the sense that the content is always the same, except that it can include new lines between words.

The solution would be simple if I had the assurance that my pattern will be predictably formatted but do not.

**Is there a way to match such "patterns" to a stream?**

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004359/regular-expression-on-stream-instead-of-string) which is an almost duplicate and the answers point towards buffering the input. The difference in my case is that I know exact strings in the pattern, except that the words are possibly also delimited by a newline (so no need for `\w*` kind of matches)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28644645/918959 is a solution that works for *ginormous* files. You just need to do a multiline regular expression that matches your brackets.

Comment: For one thing you could remove all `/n` from your text. Other than that the answer you quoted is right if you have very large texts and the opening and closing patterns could be very far apart.

Comment: What's the expected result? `the data 
I want to extract`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """
... some data ... [my opening pattern
... is here
... and can be multiline] the data
... I want to extract [my ending
... pattern which can be
... multiline as well] ... more data
... """
>>> re.findall('\[[^]]*\]\s+([^[]+)\s+\[[^]]+\]', data)
['the data \nI want to extract']
```

**UPDATE** To read a large file into chunks, I suggest the following approach:

```
## The following was modified based on ChrisA's code in
## http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1242366.
## Titled " How to read from a file to an arbitrary delimiter efficiently?"
import re

class ChunkIter:
    def __init__(self, f, delim):
        """ f: file object
        delim: regex pattern"""        
        self.f = f
        self.delim = re.compile(delim)
        self.buffer = ''
        self.part = '' # the string to return

    def read_to_delim(self):
        """Return characters up to the last delim, or None if at EOF"""

        while "delimiter not found":
            b = self.f.read(256)
            if not b: # if EOF
                self.part = None
                break
            # Continue reading to buffer
            self.buffer += b
            # Try regex split the buffer string    
            parts = self.delim.split(self.buffer)
            # If pattern is found
            if parts[:-1]:
                # Retrieve the string up to the last delim
                self.part = ''.join(parts[:-1])
                # Reset buffer string
                self.buffer = parts[-1]
                break   

        return self.part

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
        chunk = ChunkIter(f, '(\[[^]]*\]\s+(?:[^[]+)\s+\[[^]]+\])')
        while chunk.read_to_delim():
             print re.findall('\[[^]]*\]\s+([^[]+)\s+\[[^]]+\]', chunk.part)

    print 'job done.'
```

Comment: Not exactly. I am aware of regex in Python - the file I will be working in is huge so I do not want to load it to memory. But I will probably end up doing this anyway for simplicity. I will check out your solution and be back, thank you.