# Python - take words from text

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need to parse a text but the problem with it is that words which I am looking for are not on only one line.

For example the word computer can have "comp" at the end of the line and at the beginning of the line I have "uter" (without any white spaces). I want to print that I have found the word "computer"

Which is the best solution to do it, taking into account that I need an optimized algorithm, not something that checks for each letter in the word computer.

Comment: What if you were looking for foobar and foo was at the end and bar was at the start of the  next line but foo and bar were actually individual words in the text?

Comment: if they were individual words then they should have a space between them, thus before bar there would be a space (at the beginning of the new line)

Comment: So there is always a leading space? Also how large are we talking in regard to file size? If it is reasonable you can simply strip and join the lines

Comment: Is the text file small enough to load the whole file into memory?

Comment: Are you talking about '\n' newline or are you just viewing the word spread across different lines in a text editor?

Comment: if you are asking about the lenght of the file, it can be up to 100mb ~. Also, is there a way to search for foobar inside foofoobar?

Comment: no, there's no '\n' characters

Comment: Is `com\npu\ter` supposed to match? How about `com\n\nputer`?

Comment: @spoke you should add a sample of your data as it is now a bit unclear what you actually have. If there are no newlines you basically  have one line

Comment: How can there be multiple lines if the file contains no `\n` characters? BTW, 100MB of text is probably small enough to read into RAM, unless you have a _really_ old computer.

Comment: Everything will be on only one line, sorry for the mistake

Comment: If you could give us an example, it's going to save time.

Comment: The question is lacking reproducible code or even expected inputs/outputs

Comment: Then all you want is  `if word in file.read()` if you also want to match substrings

Comment: Something like [`\W(\w+\n\w+)\W*`](https://regex101.com/r/dF4rX6/1) ? This will only match words across multiple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this kind of format:

```
word in "".join(line.strip() for line in text)
```

[Here is a demo](https://repl.it/Byeg/4)

Comment: wouldn't this bring trouble if I have a large file (may even > 100mb)

Comment: What is trouble for you?

Comment: @spoke It depends on how much memory you have available, my low budget PC has 4GB.  Your alternative consists in buffering, using however an approach analogous to the one proposed by _jonotoronto_

Comment: @spoke: This post might help in reading large file in chunks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888841/how-to-read-a-file-and-extract-data-between-multiline-patterns