# Python: Searching for a RegEx in sys.stdin

Tags: regex, python-2.7, stdin

I have small python script in which I look for a pattern in the standard input, and output it after some reformatting. I have removed the complex pattern and reformatting code from the example.
Currently my code looks like this.

```
for line in re.finditer(r"""(.*)\n""", sys.stdin.read(), re.MULTILINE):
    print(line.group(0))
```

Notice the "sys.stdin.read()". This causes the script to buffer the whole input before it looks for a pattern.

How can I pass stdin as a buffer to finditer, so stdin will searched as it is inputted to the script instead of having it buffered first?

Comment: The problem here is "when does the regex engine know to try to match against the buffer"? The engine can't match across "blocks" of the buffer, it has to operate on single chunks at a time, so you need to pick how much you want to operate on at once. To specify that, you can give `.read()` a chunk size as an argument.

Comment: Why do you buffer _all_ output from stin? It looks like you want the input processed line by line... Also, you say you want to "output ot after some reformatting" -- do you want to output only the lines which are matches by your regex, or all lines including the ones which didn't match?

Comment: @Amber I disagree, a regex machine is just a state machine that handles one token at a time. If given a stream of data, it can just wait for tokens until the end of stream signal (EOF char).

Comment: @fge, I never said it's a single line pattern, I simplified it a to this single line pattern but the actual number of lines in the original pattern is unknown in advance.

Comment: @Algebra I wasn't saying that regular expressions as a concept couldn't do it - I was saying that *Python's* regex operates on fixed buffers rather than streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I missed this before I asked my question, It is already answered.

[Python regex parse stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634376/python-regex-parse-stream)

Unfortunately it's an issue with the implementation of regex in python.
See the link for possible workarounds.