# With Python can you use regex to grep through a file without pulling it all into memory?

Tags: python, regex, io

Is there any way to use python and regex to grep through a file without pulling the whole file into memory? Most of the examples I see imply that I should read the entire file into a string and then use the regular expression tools on that. But when I try something like

```
exp = re.compile("[0-9a-f]{10}")
exp.search(io.open("./data.txt","rb"))
```

I get `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. i would figure that io.open would make a "buffer" but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Use context manager: `with open(filname, 'r') as filename:`

Comment: It's easy if your regex does not cross line boundaries.  If you have multiline regexen it gets complicated.

Comment: roippi sshashank124 I'll need a little more detail before I can understand. Care to provide an answer to the question?

Comment: Did you look at [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html)?

Comment: [This seems to indicate that I can not achieve my goal here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4634376/348056)

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading. If a file contains newlines, you can easily read it a line at a time in a for loop.

Comment: I guess if you rephrase your question its a duplicate of what you found. Perhaps we should flag this one as such so others that use your phrasing may find it too.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling yep - I think that's appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file contains newlines, you can read it a line at a time:

```
with open('./data.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        print exp.search(data)
```

Comment: This is close, though really I need to be able to use multi-line regex.

Comment: @JnBrymn do you know in advance how many lines the max match would be?