# Search string with regex in large binary file (2 GB or more)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, binary

What's the best way to search (multiple) strings in a large binary file (2 GB or more) using a regular expression.

The binary data is just 'raw' data (like a memory dump) and the string is not bounded.

I am able to do this in a large text file by reading the file line by line.
I suppose I need to read the file in chunks, but then there is a boundary risk (match is located on chunk boundary)

An how can I search the binary data.

A short example is very much appreciated.

Edit:
I do not see the similarity. It's by no means clear to me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regex parse stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634376/python-regex-parse-stream)

Comment: This is *not* a strict duplicate. That ['duplicate' question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634376/python-regex-parse-stream) assumes a stream (and the answer is 'does not support'). This question asks 'how can I do it for a large file?' without assuming such a stream approach and goes on to explicitly mention boundaries .. not voting to close.

Comment: What regular expression is used? How/is it bounded?

Answer (score 1):

`read()` takes a value which a numeric indication of how many characters (bytes? multi-byte characters always confuses me), so you could read it in chunks, saving as much as is reasonable, checking with your regex. As space becomes an issue, perhaps remove only the beginning of what you've read before you read in the next chunk. This resides on having at least some guess as the length of the regex, or rather, an upper bound on it. If the regex you want to match encompasses more than the amount you can have in memory at a time, then I'm out of ideas.

```
s = ""
SOME_CHUNK_SIZE = 4096 ## 4kb, totally arbitrary
with open("large_file", "rb") as fh:
    if len(s) > SOME_BIG_NUMBER:
        s = s[SOME_CHUNK_SIZE:]
    s += fh.read(SOME_CHUNK_SIZE)
    ## do regex test now
```

That should maybe get you some of the way. You'll also need to know when you're at the end of the file, since it doesn't seem to throw an error, it just returns 0 bytes. You can either read into a temporary string and check the length, or you could try something like checking the file stats and doing arithmetic with `SOME_CHUNK_SIZE`.

Comment: `iter((lambda: file.read(SOME_BIG_NUMBER)), b"")` gets an iterable.