# Can I make a large file object iterate over lines which are split using a regex instead of \n?

Tags: python, regex, file-handling, large-files

I have a large log file and I have to extract some useful content from it, this useful content can contain `\n` in it, the log lines starts with a pattern like `Mar12 12:12:12 INFO <content goes here, can have \n in it>`

so, currently I read the logs like this

```
usefulPattern = re.compile(r'a dict: (.*)')

logfile = open('<log file path>','r')
logStartPattern = re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [A-Z]{4}')
lines = logStartPattern.split(logfile.read())
for line in lines:
    match = usefulPattern.match(line) # line may or may not contain \n depending on what the content is after initial log pattern
    if match:
        print match.groups() # do something with useful information
```

with this code I'm getting `Memory Error`, the problem I see is I'm loading the complete file in memory with `.read()`

I'm looking for a way where I can use the file object like this, so that I don't load all the file content in memory at once.

```
with open('<log file path>', 'r') as logfile:
    for line in logfile:
        match = usefulPattern.match(line) # line may or may not contain \n depending on what the content is after initial log pattern
        if match:
            print match.groups() # do something with useful information
```

for the above code to work I have to somehow override the reading behavior (probably `next` method) of file object to read up to the start of the log pattern (`[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [A-Z]{4}`) instead of `\n`

Comment: So is there any delimiter or escape character (like in CSV)? Otherwise, how do you differentiate between the two cases (newline in logged data, or simply a new log file entry altogether)?

Comment: `match = usefulPattern.seach(line)` - use `re.search` - and take Group 1 value (`match.group(1)`) if there is a match. Then use `re.search()` with your logStartPattern`.

Comment: Do all of the 'valid' log lines start with a structure as `Mar12 12:12:12 INFO` and could all the other lines be considered as continuations from the previous lines?

Comment: Some directions to resolve this issue are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634376/python-regex-parse-stream).

Comment: @zwer yes all the valid log lines start with the structure Mar12 12:12:12

Comment: @CBroe valid lines start with a pattern(`Mar12 12:12:12` this indicates the start of a log line) and in the other case the lines do not start with such pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at a way this can be achieved.,

> 1. set a start index
> 2. You basically want to iterate over every line, keep looking for a match on your pattern untill you get a match on your regex pattern.
> 3. String is identified as  starting index till that point.
> 4. append the string into a list and set new starting point as end of the pattern that was matched.
> 5. Repeat step 2 through 4.

Comment: @zwer's answer below is an implementation of the same, instead of index we work on lines(ending with \n) - which is better

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the file line by line and check for matches of the 'log start' pattern - if it matches, treat everything since the last match as a single log line, if not continue gathering lines until you have a full log line. Something like:

```
log_start = re.compile(r"[A-Z][a-z]{2}\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [A-Z]{4}")
search_pattern = re.compile(r"a dict: (.*)")

def process_log_line(line):
    if not line:  # ignore empty matches (start and optional EOF)
        return
    matches = search_pattern.search(line)  # search the full log line for your pattern
    if matches:  # if matched, do whatever you want with it...
        print(matches.groups())

buffer_line = ""  # a line buffer for multiline events
with open("<log file path>", "r") as f:
    for line in f:  # iterate over the file line by line
        if log_start.match(line):  # a new log line detected
            process_log_line(buffer_line)  # process the buffered log line
            buffer_line = line  # restart the buffer
        else:
            buffer_line += line  # add the current line to the buffer
    process_log_line(buffer_line)  # process the last buffered line
```

Make sure you just have the proper patterns (for example, your log start pattern didn't account for the day number).

Comment: yes that looks like the only simple solution I can get, will try and respond, and yes the log start pattern was there only to convey the message, its not the actual pattern